# How to reload a python library in a flask, nginx, uwsgi stack?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I've written some code for an image reconstruction server. I use a python library but it doesn't work for server so I made some changes so that it would work but it never reloads the library. I make the changes and it ignores them. I don't understand how this can be possible? Where does it get this information from and how can I make it get a fresh copy of the library every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python process started by uWSGI only interprets the source once at startup, any code changes after that will not affect the in-memory process.  You should probably just manually restart the uWSGI process when this happens.  Alternatively you can tell uWSGI to auto-reload if files or directories change: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#touch-reload.